# unable to join the worker node to k8 master node

Tags: kubernetes

I'm getting the following error, after running the kubeadm join:

```
error :
[kubelet] Downloading configuration for the kubelet from the "kubelet-config-1.12" ConfigMap in the kube-system namespace
Unauthorized
```

but the kubelet and kubeadm versions are same, but I'm still getting this error.

What's the way to authorize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how you are joining your cluster but you join your cluster with something like this:

```
kubeadm join <ip-of-your-master>:6443 --token <token> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<hash-for-cert-disc>
```

You get both when you first run `kubeadm init` on your master(s). The token expires after some time in which case you need to create a new token with `kubeadm create token`.

Comment: thank you it worked, when i generated new token, by doing kubeadm rest and then kubeadm init on master node and then using the generated new token on the worker node.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong command.
Try `kubeadm token create` instead of `kubeadm create token`.